# Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@50f097b5. Please provide a Dialect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, h2

I'm trying to make an API using Spring Boot in Kotlin and when generating the JAR file I can't succeed in running the project.
I'm still learning about it, but I haven't been able to solve this problem so far.

I'm using InteliJ IDEA Ultimate (2022.1.1)

I get this error when trying to run the file:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@50f097b5. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@50f097b5. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$NoDialectException: Cannot determine a dialect for org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@50f097b5. Please provide a Dialect.
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$2(DialectResolver.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:186)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 61 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've already tried passing a different (YML) configuration file using:
--spring.config.location

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      pool:
        core-size: 8
        keep-alive: 10s
        max-size: 16
        queue-capacity: 100
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./data/testdb
    username: admin
    password: admin

  sql:
    init:
      mode:  always
      schema-locations: classpath:sql/schema.sql

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

[Project Settings -> Artifact (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cED0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc' in build.gradle, replace it by 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).